# Bash: Get all files from a folder that match an Extended Regular Expression pattern

Tags: regex, bash

I need to collect all instances of files that match a pattern in an array.

Following `grep` pattern matches the filenames I want to match.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]\+\([-_]\?[a-zA-Z0-9]\)*-\([0-9][0-9]\?.[0-9][0-9]\?.[0-9][0-9]\?\)
```

I had to escape some characters.

Problem is, that I would like to get more knowledgable how to to this with bash `test` alone, or the `[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]` syntax respectively.

How would the grep pattern from above have to be translated into `$pattern` in order for the `[[ ... ]]` to match the example string "ruby-gem2-2.1.13" ?

Comment: Bash is using ERE, for regex, so you don't need to escape the `(` and `)` the `+` and `?` It should also work if  the `-E` flag  is used with grep.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I want to use a pattern in a Bash script that recognizes the same language and then test with `[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]`. I don't want to use grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this. The dot `.` will match any string/character when used in a regex pattern, It needs to be escaped to remove it's special meaning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*-([0-9][0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?)'
string='ruby-gem2-2.1.13'

[[ "$string"  =~ $pattern ]] && printf 'match\n'
```